# Problems with bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

I have a problem with my bibliography. [image]

As you can see in the picture, it displays volume issue and pages differently and I don't understand why. I'm using the apalike style. Can somebody help me understand what's wrong? Or is the style supposed to be like this?

Comment: From the screenshot it seems that the first reference is an `@article` in a journal while the second is formatted more like an `@inproceedings`. It is not completely unexpected that the two types would look different.

Comment: A bit of Googling suggests that despite its name, the *Carnegie-Rochester Conference Series on Public Policy* is probably more of a journal and that the type `@article` would be appropriate for the Ramey entry as well.

Comment: yes, thanks a lot, it was indeed the categorisation of the entry which was wrongly made by google scholar. Now it's solved, thanks again!